# How to access role in JSP using spring security?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I want to print a user role in JSP? I know there is a spring -security tag called as `<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>`
Using this tag I can access the user name..but how to access and print the current role in jsp?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since `principal` refers to your `UserDetails` object, if you inspect that object the roles are stored under `public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() { .. }`.

That said, if you merely want to print the roles on the screen, do this:-

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities"/>
```

Answer (score 21):

Use [getAuthorities](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html#getAuthorities%28%29) or write your own implementation of userdetails and create a convenience method.

or :

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">
 This content will only be visible to users who have
 the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.
</sec:authorize>
```

from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) .

Comment: how to use getAuthorities from jsp ?

Comment: just use nromal bean convention : <sec:authentication property="principal.authorities"/>

Answer (score 5):

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities" var="authorities" />
<c:forEach items="${authorities}" var="authority" varStatus="vs">
<p>${authority.authority}</p>
</c:forEach>
```